# CheckBox in table

Tags: aem-6

This question is regarding aem 6.3

I have an assignment that requires me to use a checkbox in the table. But I notice that when I do that, I am unable to create a new row through the workflow. May I know is there a workaround over it?

In my console logs, I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at child.handleAccessibility...
```

Am I suppose to create an id first? If so how do I do that?

Thanks

Norman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be that aem currently has a bug where the title of the checkbox cannot be hidden if not it will face the aforementioned error. So the solution is not hide the title but let it be blank.

This is more of an issue of that the id cannot be recognised, instead of unable to create a new row through the workflow, that resulted in the latter issue.